# Creating Links to share on specific location of pdf and html files on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, pdf

I’m creating .pdf and .html documents for viewing on the internet. I have inserted social sharing icons in those documents, including one for Facebook.  I have hyperlinked those icons to permit sharing of specific pages on the timeline of the particular user that is viewing the document.

Here’s my problem, using a specific example:

•   ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/eVOICE9711.pdf#page=14
 – put this in the browser address box and it goes to the appropriate destination as indicated (page 14 of the PDF file).

•   www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http: //ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/eVOICE9711.pdf#page=14
– put this in the browser address box and it brings up FB share dialogue box but only creates a link to, and displays, ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/eVOICE9711.pdf

Similarly:

•   ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/9711/eVOICE9711.html#p=14 – put this in the browser address box and it goes to the appropriate destination (page 14 of the html file)

.
•   www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http: //ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/9711/eVOICE9711.html#p=14 – put this in the browser address box and it brings up FB share dialogue box but only creates a link to, and displays, ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/9711/eVOICE9711.html

Note: I placed a space after the // in the links above so that this message didn't exceed the number of links I am allowed to include.  The space is NOT there in the actual links/urls I'm creating.

It would appear as though FB is stripping the #xxxxxxxxxx string in each case.

How do I resolve this issue, enabling me to hyperlink the FB share buttons with a successful result?

Answer (score 0):

use %23 (url encoding) instead of the hash, so

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://ifcamedia.org/eVOICE/9711/eVOICE9711.html%23p=14